# RegEx, find a match in a line and print it

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

From a file structured like this:

```
..............................
Delimiter [1]
..............................
blablabla
..............................
Delimiter CEO [2]
..............................
blabla
..............................
Delimiter [3]
..............................

[...]

..............................
Delimiter CEO [n-1]
..............................
blablabla
..............................
Delimiter [n]
..............................
```

I wrote a code that extracts all the delimiters, but also some lines that I don't need. Those lines that I don't need cause [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390741/extract-text-between-two-delimiters-from-a-text-file/51391246?noredirect=1#comment89799711_51391246) to not run proprerly.
I'd like to save in a new .txt file a line if in that line there's the regular expression " [ a number ]". So, to be more accurate in the extraction, I wrote this code in python (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842931/10095971)) using re:

```
import re
with open('testoestratto.txt','r',encoding='UTF-8') as myFile:
    text = myFile.readlines()
    text = [frase.rstrip('\n') for frase in text]
    regex = r'\[\d+\]'
    new_file=[]
    for lines in text:
       match = re.search(regex, lines, re.MULTILINE)
       if match:            
           new_line = match.group() + '\n'            
           new_file.append(new_line)

with open('prova.txt', 'w') as f:     
     f.seek(0)    
     f.writelines(new_file)
```

But, in the 'prova.txt' file I could find only the regular expressions so I have a file with [1], [2], ... [n-1], [n].

Comment: Please see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new_file` is a list of found matches in the file (that you fill with `match.group()` + newline).

You may check if there is a `\[\d+]` match in a line and output the line into the new file:

```
import re

reg = re.compile(r'\[\d+]') # Matches a [ char, followed with 1+ digits and then ]

with open('prova.txt', 'w') as f:     # open file for writing
    with open('testoestratto.txt','r',encoding='UTF-8') as myFile: # open file for reading
        for line in myFile:           # read myFile line by line
            if reg.search(line):      # if there is a match anywhere in a line
                f.write(line)         # write the line into the new file
```