# Python - live update graphs; to plot Time on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

i have a python script that collects data from a server in the form of

```
<hh-mm-ss>,<ddd>
```

here, the first field is Date and the second field is an integer digit. this data is being written into a file.

i have another thread running which is plotting a live graph from the file which i mentioned in the above paragraph.

so this file has data like,

```
<hh-mm-ss>,<ddd>
<hh-mm-ss>,<ddd>
<hh-mm-ss>,<ddd>
<hh-mm-ss>,<ddd>
```

Now i want to plot a time series Matplotlib graph with the above shown data.
but when i try , it throws an error saying,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '15:53:09'
```

when i have normal data like shown below, things are fine

```
<ddd>,<ddd>
<ddd>,<ddd>
<ddd>,<ddd>
<ddd>,<ddd>
```

**UPDATE**
my code that generates graph from the file i have described above is shown below,

```
def animate(i):

    pullData = open("sampleText.txt","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,yar)
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
def animate(i):
    print("inside animate")
    pullData = open("sampleText.txt","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            timeX=datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S")
            xar.append(timeX.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            yar.append(float(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,yar)
```

Now i am getting the error at this line (`ax1.plot(xar,yar)`)
how will i get over this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse an integer from a string representing a timestamp. Of course it fails.

In order to be able to use the timestamps in a plot, you need to parse them to the proper type, e.g., `datetime.time` or `datetime.datetime`. You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, `dateutil.parser.parse()` or maybe also `time.strptime()` for this.

Plotting the data is straight-forward, then. Have a look at the interactive plotting mode: `matplotlib.pyplot.ion()`.

For reference/further reading:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil
- http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime
- http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion
- [Plotting time in Python with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1574088/1025391)
- [How to iterate over the file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5733419/1025391)

---

Based on your code I have created an example. I have inlined some notes as to why I think it's better to do it this way.

```
# use with-statement to make sure the file is eventually closed
with open("sampleText.txt") as f:
    data = []
    # iterate the file using the file object's iterator interface
    for line in f:
        try:
            t, f = line.split(",")
            # parse timestamp and number and append it to data list
            data.append((datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S"), float(f)))
        except ValueError:
            # something went wrong: inspect later and continue for now
            print "failed to parse line:", line
# split columns to separate variables
x,y = zip(*data)
# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

For further reading:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93953/discussion-between-moooeeeep-and-vasanth-nag-k-v).

Answer (score -1):

The error tells you the cause of the problem: You're trying to convert a string, such as `'15:53:09'`, into an integer. This string is not a valid number.

Instead, you should either look into using a `datetime` object from the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module to work with date/time things or at least `split`ting the string into fields using `':'` as the delimiter and the using each field separately.

Consider this brief demo:

```
>>> time = '15:53:09'
>>> time.split(':')
['15', '53', '09']
>>> [int(v) for v in time.split(':')]
[15, 53, 9]
>>> int(time)  # expect exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '15:53:09'
>>>
```