# Add a value to a column and print results

Tags: python

I have a file like this

```
Daniel 400 411 f
Mark 976 315 g
```

I would like to add 20 to line[2] and subtract 20 from line[1] and print new results overwriting this lines or to a new file.This is my try.

```
f=open('w', 'r')
r = open('w2','a')
lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
  new_list = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
  q_start=int(new_list[1]) - 20
  q_end=int(new_list[2]) + 20
  # I think something is missing here, but I don't know what
  r.writelines(lines)
f.close()
r.close()
```

Expected outcome

```
Daniel 380 431 f
Mark 956 335 g
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f=open('w', 'r')
r=open('w2','a')
lines=f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    new_list = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
    new_list[1] = str(int(new_list[1]) - 20)
    new_list[2] = str(int(new_list[2]) + 20)
    r.write("\t".join(new_list)+"\n")

f.close()
r.close()
```

This should works. Basically, you need split your line into segments first, then modify the parts you want, and stitch them together.

Comment: I tried smth similar like this using join but did not work, probably I made some mistake. Anyway your's is working, thanks!

Comment: And you can also try the `with` syntax in Ami Tavory's answer. It's more convenient and safer in case you forget to close the files.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need to read in all the lines into memory, then loop over them. It just lengthens the code and is less efficient. Instead, try

```
with open('w2','w') as out:
    for line in open('w', 'r'):
        new_list = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
        q_start=int(new_list[1]) - 20
        q_end=int(new_list[2]) + 20
        out.write('\t'.join([line[0], str(q_start), str(q_end), line[3]]) + '\n')
```

Note the use of [`with` to open `'w2'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement), and the [more efficient loop over the `'w'`'s lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733419/how-to-iterate-over-the-file-in-python).

---

**Edit Addressing Comment**

Note that if you have multiple columns (but still need to update only those at columns at 1 and 2), you can change the last line to

```
        out.write('\t'.join([line[0], str(q_start), str(q_end)] + line[3: ]) + '\n')
```

Comment: this is good, but what If I have many up to 10 arguments in a line?

Comment: Do you still need to only change those at 1 and 2?

Comment: yes, I change only at 1 and 2 but I have more than 10 columns in line and I don't want to write all, cos I also thought abt this way, but I was sure there was a more efficient and nice way..

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have already accepted an answer, but still, here is my comment. There are a couple of mistakes in your code. The first is that even though you calculate the values correctly, you store them into two variable(`q_start` and `q_end`) that are not used afterwards.

The second mistake is that you write to the output file the unaltered original data (the `lines` list) and do so inside the loop (check your identations). hence, I believe that your output was an N repetition of the original file, where N is the number of lines in it.

The possible thirs mistake is using `'a'` to open the output file. If there was any content in it, it would not be deleted. Since I am not sure of your intentions, this may not be a mistake, but pay attention if you wanted a clean slate or not.

Finally, here is my version of your code, minimally altered to work. I left the `'a'` in the output file open process because I did not know if you did this on purpose.

```
f=open('w.txt', 'r')
r = open('w2.txt','a')
lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
  print line  
  new_list = line.rstrip('\r\n').split(' ')
  new_list[1]=str(int(new_list[1]) - 20)
  new_list[2]=str(int(new_list[2]) + 20)  
  r.write('\t'.join(new_list)+"\n")
f.close()
r.close()
```

I hope this helps.